# Twilio - Understanding if outbound call is transferred by receiver

Tags: node.js, twilio

Using Node.JS and the Twilio API I can easily see when a transfer initiated by my Twilio code is answered using Call Status Events. But, what if the person I am calling transfers my call?

Is there anything in the Twilio API that will tell me the call is being transferred, is currently on hold, and when that transfer is answered?

**Desired Flow:**

1. Twilio Bot calls Number
2. Receptionist answers
3. Twilio Bot asks to speak with a salesperson
4. Receptionist says they will transfer the call, and begins the transfer
5. Twilio Bot is put on hold and hears Silence/Ringing/Music/Automated "pease wait. You are # in the que" messages
6. Salesperson answers
7. Twilio Bot greets and continues the conversation with Salesperson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

The information is hidden behind the receptionists PBX, and not exposed outside that platform. The transfer is basically invisible to Twilio or any external parties from a signaling perspective.